# Issue with getting this java program to display the proper whitespace in the answer

Tags: java

So my problem is, my output seems to be correct except it is giving me 0/10 for credit because of the whitespace after the output counts down to one in each situation. It is saying I need a newline after the one but I have tried several things and it's the same output every time.

2.31 LAB: Hailstone sequence
Given a positive integer n, the following rules will always create a sequence that ends with 1, called the hailstone sequence:

If n is even, divide it by 2
If n is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1 (i.e. 3n +1)
Continue until n is 1
Write a program that reads an integer as input and prints the hailstone sequence starting with the integer entered. Format the output so that ten integers, each separated by a tab character (\t), are printed per line.

The output format can be achieved as follows:

```
System.out.print(n + "\t");
```

Ex: If the input is:

25
the output is:

25   76   38   19   58   29   88   44   22   11
34   17   52   26   13   40   20   10   5    16
8    4    2    1

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    n = scnr.nextInt();

    System.out.print(n + "\t");
    int count = 1;

    while (n > 1) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n * 1 / 2;
        } else {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
        }

        System.out.print(n + "\t");
        count++;

        if (count % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }

}
```

This is what I came up with and I am new to java so it is probably something I am overthinking, any thoughts would be appreciated.

["enter image description here" is not an image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa5nU.png)

Comment: `System.out.print("\n"); ` -> `System.out.println(); `

Comment: I'd also consider looking at `String#format` and `System.out.printf` for additional formatting options

Comment: `n = n * 1 / 2` can be simplifed to `n /= 2`.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, I guess you can trick it by just skipping the tab on the 10'th print. So instead of your normal `System.out.print(n + "\t");` print try:

```
if ((count + 1) % 10 == 0) {
  System.out.print(n);
} else {
  System.out.print(n + "\t");
}
```

instead of your normal print.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and see if the output changes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just needed to change the order of the code a little and make (n != 1) and System.out.print(n) at the very end. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

try this, changed the print condition to exclude the tab for end value and when n is 1.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    n = scnr.nextInt();

    System.out.print(n + "\t");
    int count = 1;

    while (n > 1) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n * 1 / 2;
        } else {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
        }
        
        count++;
        if (count % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }else{
            if(n==1) {
                System.out.print(n);
            }else{
                System.out.print(n + "\t");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did try that, thank you. I keep getting the same output error. whitespace differs.

Comment: modified the print condition to exclude the tab for row end value and when n is 1.